# Designing DDD aggregates for pairing mechanism

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

I'm developing an application following Domain-Driven Design (DDD) principles, and I need help modeling the following requirements:

**Main Purpose:**

An application to control sound `Player`s (Speaker) within a `HouseHold` through `RemoteControl`.
Think of a `RemoteControl` as a sound mixer with 1-N channels, Where each `Channel` controls different `Player`.

**Relationships:**

- Each `Player` is associated with a single `HouseHold`.
- A `HouseHold` can have one or many `Player`s.
- `RemoteControl` is not associated with a `HouseHold`.
- Each `RemoteControl` has a list of `Channel`s.
- Each `Channel` is uniquely identified by its position (index) within the `RemoteControl`.

**Channel-Player Pairing:**

- A `Channel` can be paired with a `Player`. This pairing designates that the `Channel` controls the associated `Player`.
- A single `RemoteControl` cannot be paired with the same `Player` on multiple channels.
- However, different instances of `RemoteControl` can be paired with the same `Player`, once each.
- The goal of this pairing is to locate a `Player` not by its ID (`PlayerId`) but through the `RemoteControl`-`Channel` pair.

**Remote Control Details:**

- The `RemoteControl` is essentially a simple IoT device with an array of volume inputs.
- It is unaware of the players and their IDs.
- Each request from the client includes `remoteControlId`, `channelPosition`, `eventType` and `value`.
- Using the pairing information, the application should identify the associated `Player` and update its state accordingly.

---

This is what I came up by now:
The following entities with the intention of defining `Player`, `RemoteControl`, and `HouseHold` as roots.

`Player`:

- id
- houseHoldId
- name
- volume

`RemoteControl`:

- id
- channelsCount / listOfChannels

`HouseHold`:

- id
- Map<PairdChannel,String> map/List pairs

`PairedChannel`: (V/O)

- remoteControlId
- channelPosition

`Pair`:

- id
- playerId
- pairedChannel

And the relevant use-cases in app services might be:

HouseHoldAppService:

```js
function pair(houseHoldId, remoteId, channelPosition, playerId) {
    houseHold = repo.getById(houseHoldId)
    if (!houseHold) throw...
    remote = remoteService.getById(remoteId);
    if (!remote) throw 
    player = playerService.getById(playerId);
    if (!player) throw 
    pairedChannel = new PairedChannel(remote.id, channelPosition);
    pair = Pair.create(pairedChannel, player.id);
    houseHold.add(pair);
    houseHoldRepo.add(houseHold);
}
```

RemoteControlService:

```js
function changeVolume(remoteId, channelPosition, value) {
    pair = houseHoldService.findPair(remoteId, channelPosition);
    if (!pair) throw
    playerAppService.changeVolume(pair.playerId, value);
}
```

PlayerAppService:

```js
function changeVolume(playerId, value) {
    player = repo.getById(playerId)
    if (!player) throw
    if (!player.changeVolume(value)) return
    repo.store(player)
    dispatch(player.dequeue())
}
```

An high-level flow of the app:

1. Dedicated driver emit new event when speaker is found (with speaker data + houseHoldId)
2. `PlayerAppService` catches this event, and create new `Player` domain object.
3. `HouseHoldAppService` catches the `PlayerCreatedEvent`, and if the `HouseHold` is not exists - it creates it.
4. Another dedicated driver emits event when Remote control is connected.
5. `RemoteControlAppService` catches this event, and create new `RemoteControl` domain object
6. The user pair `Channel` to `Player` by using API such:
   url: `/household/:id/pair/`
   body: `{ remoteId, channelPosition, playerId }`
7. The Remote can change the volume of the paired `Player` using API such:
   url: `/remotecontrol/:id/channel/:channel/changeVolume/:volume`
8. The dedicated speaker driver can always emit events to change the volume of the `Player` by it's id. For example:  `event: changeVolume, data: { playerId, volume }`

---

I'm seeking advice and/or feedback on how to structure these relationships and implement the pairing mechanism effectively within the context of Domain-Driven Design.
Any insights, advice, or code examples related to aggregate design would be appreciated.